# How to load jQuery-ui with Asp Core+ Angular 4 template from VS 2017

Tags: node.js, angular, jquery-ui, npm, webpack

I use Asp Core+webpack+ Angular 4 template from  VS 2017.how do I load  jQuery-ui,
I put it to  webpack.config.vendor.js:

```
const treeShakableModules = [
    '@angular/animations',
    '@angular/common',
    '@angular/compiler',
    '@angular/core',
    '@angular/forms',
    '@angular/http',
    '@angular/platform-browser',
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
    '@angular/router',
    'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css',
    'zone.js',
    'virtual-keyboard',
    'jquery-ui'                   //Here
```

but I don't think it is correct

what is the right way to include js/css files to webpack?

thanks

Comment: found this  https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-jquery-ui     but  adding these 2 lines require('webpack-jquery-ui');
require('webpack-jquery-ui/css');   give errors

Answer (score 1):

You should know by now, but npm dependencies are added in `packages.json`; this one should go in the `Dependencies` section. You will also need `'@types/jquery-ui'` in the `DevDependencies` section to access the API from inside TypeScript, which you should import in your code. Once you modify the file and save, allow a minute or two for the project to update (you can see the progress in the npm section of the Output Window). There may be several other steps needed (like adding `<script>` and `<link>` directives in your page) as I did not use jQuery UI myself.